# How to send whole object to spark map in python?

Tags: python, apache-spark

The official [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/rdd-programming-guide.html) provides an example of applying `map` on an `rdd` within a class definition. It is like this,

```
class MyClass(object):
    def func(self, s):
        return s
    def doStuff(self, rdd):
        return rdd.map(self.func)
```

The Spark documentation says, "Here, if we create a new `MyClass` instance and call `doStuff` on it, the map inside there references the `func1` method of that `MyClass` instance, so the whole object needs to be sent to the cluster. It is similar to writing `rdd.map(x => this.func1(x))`."

However, I am unable to make this work. I am trying the following,

```
corpus = [["B","B","A","C","A","C","A","A","B","A"], ["C", "Z", "Z", "Z", "D"]]

rdd = sc.parallelize(corpus)

obj = MyClass()

obj.doStuff(rdd)
```

**What does sending the whole object mean?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't `obj = MyObject()` be `obj = MyClass()`?

Comment: @oldwooki thanks, corrected the typo.